# Prevent plotly express scatter to group dots by color group on a categorical x axis

Tags: plotly, scatter-plot, plotly-python

I want to plot the following dataframe, rows being ordered by the value of the "freq" column :

```
# import pandas as pd
# import plotly.express as px

               EC_name            freq         EC_class
1.1.1.1        1.1.1.1        1.000000  Oxidoreductases
2.7.7.41      2.7.7.41        1.000000     Transferases
4.2.99.18    4.2.99.18        1.000000           Lyases
2.3.1.12      2.3.1.12        1.000000     Transferases
1.5.1.2        1.5.1.2        1.000000  Oxidoreductases
...                ...             ...              ...
1.13.12.22  1.13.12.22        0.006494  Oxidoreductases
2.1.1.114    2.1.1.114        0.006494     Transferases
3.6.1.15      3.6.1.15        0.006494       Hydrolases
1.21.4.3      1.21.4.3        0.006494  Oxidoreductases
1.17.3.2      1.17.3.2        0.006494  Oxidoreductases
```

First attempt was as expected:

```
fig = px.scatter(df,
    x = "EC_name",
    y = "freq",
    height=500,
    width=500,
    labels={"EC_name": "ECs", "freq": "Frequence in observations"})
```

[image]

However when I add a color code `color="EC_class"`, it messes up the result by grouping categories together / ordering the x axis by `EC_name` and not by the value of the `freq` column:

[image]

How do I add colors and keep the original ordering ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Adding `category_orders={"EC_name": df.index}` in the `px.scatter` function solved the issue.